# Parsing errors in Chrome

Tags: javascript

```html
<script type="module" id="user-code">

try {
    someUnknownReference;
} catch (error) { 
    console.log(error) // correct
    console.log(error.toString()); // incorrect
    console.log(error.stack.toString().split('\n')); // incorrect - line number and filename is wrong
}
  
    //# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbImluZGV4LmpzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbImxrc2xrcyJdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IkFBQUFBLE1BQU0iLCJmaWxlIjoiYnVuZGxlLmpzIiwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsibGtzbGtzIl19
</script>
```

I'm building a browser based code editor using Babel. All is working well, however I can't for the life of me extract the line number and file name out of the errors that happen during run time.

The example above is a simplified version of what I'm doing. I'm injecting a string into a `script tag` e.g `scriptTag.innerHTML = bundledCode;`

The first `console.log` prints exactly what I want to parse e.g it has the file name and correct line number which it gets from the sourcemap

```
ReferenceError: someUnknownReference is not defined
    at index.js:1
```

However, as soon as I try to do anything with the error e.g the second `console.log`, I lose the line number and file name.

```
ReferenceError: someUnknownReference is not defined
```

My guess is maybe it's losing the reference to the sourcemap when we try to parse the object?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think Chrome console is automatically consuming source maps to provide the correct error msg if you're console logging the error. Not if you're grabbing the actual string. Do you need something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourcemapped-stacktrace?

Comment: This does look promising, and seems to be trying to solve this issue. It doesn't seem to work for my example though. I think because the source scripts are in memory, so it cannot find them. I'll do some digging through the source code of that lib though to see if holds the key!